# EM_POSFROMCHAR not returning proper value when caret is at the last position

Tags: .net, c++, windows, winforms, c++-cli

I am facing a weird issue with `EM_POSFROMCHAR`.

I am trying to get the client area coordinates of the current caret position in a text control. This works fine with all the other scenarios, but always returning `-1` when the caret is at the last position.

I'm doing this in a C++ application (wxWidgets). But to make it easy to post here, I have made a C++/CLI port of it. Here is the relevant code (extracting LOWWORD and HIWORD are removed for simplicity).

```
HWND handle = (HWND) textControl->Handle.ToPointer();
LRESULT rc = ::SendMessage(handle, EM_POSFROMCHAR, textControl->SelectionStart, 0);
MessageBox::Show(rc.ToString());
```

This returns `-1` always. I have tried to pass `textControl->SelectionStart - 1` and it gave a proper value. For some reason it is not working for the last position. This works well with RichText control.

I figured out .NET framework provides an API to do this for managed clients. `TextBoxBase.GetPositionFromCharIndex`. This function also produces the same result as explained above. I had a look at it using Reflector and they use the same code to get the position.

I have the following questions.

1. Why am I not getting the proper values when caret is at the last position?
2. If this is a problem with `EM_POSFROMCHAR`, what is the workaround to fix this?

My intention is to show a context menu at the caret position while users type the text. Something similar to what visual studio has.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by 'at the last position' you mean behind the last visible character?

> If the character is a line delimiter, the returned coordinates indicate a point just beyond the last visible character in the line. If the specified index is greater than the index of the **last character in the control**, the control returns -1.

By that logic, if you have an edit control with, say 2 lines, and you give it the index after the last character in line 1, it calculates the coordinates of the newline character.
There is no such character on the last line or in single line edit controls.

As for a workaround, I don't think there's much in the way of edit control messages. You might want to have a look at [GetCaretPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648402%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) though.